# Elegant way to apply curried function to indexed traversal

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I want to compose a curried function

```
f :: i -> a -> b
```

With an indexed traversal

```
l :: IndexedTraversal' i s a
```

apply it to an `s` and get back a `[b]`.

I came up with

```
s ^.. l . withIndex . to (uncurry f)
```

But I would like a combinator `itoListByOf` that would allow me to do this

```
s & itoListByOf l f
```

Like

```
itoListByOf :: IndexedGetting i (Endo [b]) s a -> (i-> a -> b) -> s -> [b]
itoListByOf l f = ifoldrOf l (\i a -> (f i a :)) []
```

But I want to make sure I'm not missing this combinator hiding in the library with a more general type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have correctly defined the itoListByOf function to achieve your goal. While there are many combinators in the lens library that provide similar functionality, I don't think there is a more general combinator with exactly the type you are looking for.

The ifoldrOf function you use in your definition of itoListByOf is itself a very general function that can be used to traverse any IndexedFold and accumulate results. The itoListByOf function simply specializes ifoldrOf to the case where the accumulation function is a function that applies the f function to each element of the fold and appends the result to a list.

In summary, I believe your implementation of itoListByOf is a good one, and there is not a more general combinator with the same type in the lens library.

Comment: It's weird that `view` and `iview` correspond to `toListOf` and `itoListOf`, but there's nothing that corresponds to `views` and `iviews` for lists.